# How do I combine these two regular expressions into one?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a rudimentary lexer using regular expressions in JavaScript and I have two regular expressions (one for single quoted strings and one for double quoted strings) which I wish to combine into one. These are my two regular expressions (I added the `^` and `$` characters for testing purposes):

```
var singleQuotedString = /^'(?:[^'\\]|\\'|\\\\|\\\/|\\b|\\f|\\n|\\r|\\t|\\u[0-9A-F]{4})*'$/gi;
var doubleQuotedString = /^"(?:[^"\\]|\\"|\\\\|\\\/|\\b|\\f|\\n|\\r|\\t|\\u[0-9A-F]{4})*"$/gi;
```

Now I tried to combine them into a single regular expression as follows:

```
var string = /^(["'])(?:[^\1\\]|\\\1|\\\\|\\\/|\\b|\\f|\\n|\\r|\\t|\\u[0-9A-F]{4})*\1$/gi;
```

However when I test the input `"Hello"World!"` it returns `true` instead of `false`:

```
alert(string.test('"Hello"World!"')); //should return false as a double quoted string must escape double quote characters
```

I figured that the problem is in `[^\1\\]` which should match any character besides matching group `\1` (which is either a single or a double quote - the delimiter of the string) and `\\` (which is the backslash character).

The regular expression correctly filters out backslashes and matches the delimiters, but it doesn't filter out the delimiter within the string. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Note that I referred to Crockford's [railroad diagrams](http://json.org/) to write the regular expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't refer to a matched group inside a character class: `(['"])[^\1\\]`. Try something like this instead:

```
(['"])((?!\1|\\).|\\[bnfrt]|\\u[a-fA-F\d]{4}|\\\1)*\1
```

*(you'll need to add some more escapes, but you get my drift...)*

A quick explanation:

```
(['"])             # match a single or double quote and store it in group 1
(                  # start group 2
  (?!\1|\\).       #   if group 1 or a backslash isn't ahead, match any non-line break char
  |                #   OR
  \\[bnfrt]        #   match an escape sequence
  |                #   OR
  \\u[a-fA-F\d]{4} #   match a Unicode escape
  |                #   OR
  \\\1             #   match an escaped quote
)*                 # close group 2 and repeat it zero or more times
\1                 # match whatever group 1 matched
```

Comment: I never knew you could do something like `(?!\1|\\).`. On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp "RegExp - MDN") it says that `'x(?!y)' matches 'x' only if 'x' is not followed by 'y'`.

Comment: @Aadit M Shah - Its a poor analogy. You are always at a position between characters in regular expressions, like a cursor. Assertions stand still and `(?!)` and `(?=)` always refer to whats to the right of the current position. Its immaterial what is to the left of it other than if it didn't match, you would not be at this assertion.

Comment: @Aadit M Shah - No need to tell Microsoft the errors of its ways, its a company that consumes technology (with docs). Just google `'x' only if 'x' is not followed by 'y'`

Comment: @sin - MDN stands for Mozilla Developer Network. Not Microsoft Developer Network. That's MSDN. Mozilla is the pioneer in JavaScript technology. Which self respecting programmer would go to Microsoft for any purpose?

Comment: @Aadit M Shah - Haha, sorry about that. That one line used to explain negative lookahead is pretty much the standard across multiple flavors of regex (as are many other 1 liners). Not too informational really..

Answer (score 2):

This should work too (raw regex).
If speed is a factor, this is the 'unrolled' method, said to be the fastest for this kind of thing.

```
(['"])(?:(?!\\|\1).)*(?:\\(?:[\/bfnrt]|u[0-9A-F]{4}|\1)(?:(?!\\|\1).)*)*/1
```

Expanded

```
(['"])            # Capture a quote
(?:
   (?!\\|\1).             # As many non-escape and non-quote chars as possible
)*

(?:                       
    \\                     # escape plus,
    (?:
        [\/bfnrt]          # /,b,f,n,r,t or u[a-9A-f]{4} or captured quote
      | u[0-9A-F]{4}
      | \1
    )
    (?:                
        (?!\\|\1).         # As many non-escape and non-quote chars as possible
    )*
)*

/1                # Captured quote
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always just create a larger regex by just using the alternation operator on the smaller regexes

```
/(?:single-quoted-regex)|(?:double-quoted-regex)/
```

Or explicitly:

```
var string = /(?:^'(?:[^'\\]|\\'|\\\\|\\\/|\\b|\\f|\\n|\\r|\\t|\\u[0-9A-F]{4})*'$)|(?:^"(?:[^"\\]|\\"|\\\\|\\\/|\\b|\\f|\\n|\\r|\\t|\\u[0-9A-F]{4})*"$)/gi;
```

---

Finally, if you want to avoid the code duplication, you can build up this regex dynamically, using the `new Regex` constructor.

```
var quoted_string = function(delimiter){
    return ('^' + delimiter + '(?:[^' + delimiter + '\\]|\\' + delimiter + '|\\\\|\\\/|\\b|\\f|\\n|\\r|\\t|\\u[0-9A-F]{4})*' + delimiter + '$').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
    //in the general case you could consider using a regex excaping function to avoid backslash hell.
};

var string = new RegExp( '(?:' + quoted_string("'") + ')|(?:' + quoted_string('"') + ')' , 'gi' );
```

Comment: I though of that; and then I thought that there must be a better way to do it. =)

Comment: Would you happen to know why `[^\1\\]` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @AaditMShah: I just don't think you can use backreferences inside the classes like that. In any case I wrote down a version that does not duplicate the regex, but now you have to decide if you think it is more readable or not ;)